# How to uninstall SBT?

Tags: uninstall

My current installed Simple Build Tool (SBT) is corrupted and I want to reinstall it. The problem is I didn't install SBT through `sudo apt-get` command. I followed the tutorial here: https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004/wiki/ToolsSetup

Instructions that I followed from the webpage:

- Download sbt from here: http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.4/sbt.tgz
- Unpack the archive to a directory of your choice
- Add the bin/ directory to the PATH environment variable. Open the file ~/.bashrc in an editor (create it if it doesn’t exist) and add the following line export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH

So how do I uninstall SBT on Ubuntu in the first place?

I tried running `sudo apt-get remove sbt` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

This is what I get when I run the above command:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove sbt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'sbt' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ax25-node libax25 libossp-uuid16 openbsd-inetd
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 324 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to uninstall. Just delete the directory you got from unpacking the archive and remove the `export PATH` line from your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the directory where you uppacked `sbt.tgz`. The contents of the file seems to indicate there is a

```
./sbt/
```

directory with a license file and a ./bin/ that has some jar files. Files in ./bin/

[image]

So there is nothing indicating there is some sort of uninstal. Generally this means you need to `rm` the direcory (`rm -r ./sbt/` from where you unpacked it).

After that you need to revert this manually:

> Add the bin/ directory to the PATH environment variable. Open the file ~/.bashrc in an editor (create it if it doesn’t exist) and add the following line export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH

So Open the file ~/.bashrc  and delete `export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH`